# Users getting "Unable to obtain exclusive access" Error

Tags: locking

My users are attempting to work in records and occasionally get the error message of `Unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: [id]`. This error is intermittent and I cannot find the source.

I have reviewed [several](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20921/can-anybody-explain-the-unable-to-lock-row-error) of the [other threads](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190055/unable-to-lock-row-error) regarding [this issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21375/can-some-one-correct-this-error-modified-one), and it seems all of them have to do with a specific set of code. I can also say [account data skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/01/reducing-lock-contention-by-avoiding-account-data-skews.html) is not the cause.

This is an inherited org, so there may be something big that I am missing. I have reviewed the triggers, Apex jobs, background jobs, and Bulk Data Load Jobs.

For a very specific example, a user got this error when he tried to update the phone number on the record. The only things on the trigger are a HEDA trigger TDTM_Contact, and a DupeBlocker trigger DB_ContactTrigger. I cannot (and perhaps don't know how to) find the contact ID in any jobs (bulk, background, or Apex). The contact object does not have any custom process builders or workflows or flows.

One possible explanation might be the connection we have with Marketing Cloud? But there are not any connections to Contact outside of a data connection.

As a stretch... I will say that I have noticed this org has to be refreshed more than I have ever experienced before. I will often get notices that I have "modified the record" and that I need to refresh - even when I didn't make any changes. I've been wondering if that is a connection problem on our premises?

I'm at the end of my rope and I can't figure it out. Should I open a ticket with Salesforce, or will they even be able to do anything?

Comment: This question would need deeper investigation. It could be batch/scheduled/future/queueable jobs, asynchronous flows and workflow rules, third party integrations, etc. Just because you don't have data skew doesn't mean you can't run into a situation where there's just too much stuff running in the background.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be something like that. How do I take an id and check those? I opened up the jobs, but they don't give me the ids of what was run. This happens infrequently enough that setting up a logger on the user is pointless and very hit or miss. I maybe need some direction of HOW to diagnose this.

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose an intermittent problem like this. I think Support (Tier III) or R&D could probably look at the server logs and find out more, as long as you have an approximate time frame and record ID. As a customer (e.g. you or I), it's *really* hard to figure this out on your own. How I'd fix this? Start turning off asynchronous processes until the problem goes away completely, then fix whatever it is that was broken. But this might well end up taking weeks or months using this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up, in case anyone else runs into this same issue.

Open a case with SFDC, just as @sfdcfox recommends. They are able to run diagnostics on what is locking the record. In my specific case it has to do with triggers running for 2+ minutes.

This allows me to diagnose better and find a solution.